# Angular sort function throws error when item is added in Firebase

Tags: angular

I have asked my peers this but they weren't able to come up with a solution and I have been working on this problem for days. The program works great when I load it up and don't do anything to the database, but when I add some information in it, the database doesn't load on the application and it throws the error "_this.documents.sort is not a function". Also, I have written a console.log for debugging and it shows that I am pulling from the database just fine. When I remove the line, it says that my `this.documents.slice()` is wrong too.

Here is my firebase if anyone is curious: https://cmsproject-4163e.firebaseio.com/

This is where I am getting my error (Note: this is only part of my code, I am not going to show you all of my code since these are the classes that are throwing the errors):

My documents.service.ts file:

```
import { Injectable, EventEmitter } from '@angular/core';
import { MOCKDOCUMENTS } from './MOCKDOCUMENTS';
import { Subject } from 'rxjs';
import { Document } from './document.model';
import {HttpClient, HttpHeaders, HttpResponse } from'@angular/common/http'

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})

export class DocumentsService {

 documentSelectedEvent = new EventEmitter<Document>();
  documentListChangedEvent = new Subject<Document[]>();
  maxDocumentId: number;
  documents: Document[] = [];
  id: string;

  constructor(private http: HttpClient, private documentService: DocumentsService) {
      this.documents = MOCKDOCUMENTS;
    this.maxDocumentId = this.getMaxId();
  }

  getDocuments() {
    this.http.get('https://cmsproject-4163e.firebaseio.com/documents.json')
    .subscribe(
      (responseData: Document[]) => {
        this.documents = responseData;
        console.log(this.documents);
        this.documents.sort((a,b) => (a.name > b.name) ? 1 : ((b.name > a.name) ? -1 : 0));
        this.documentListChangedEvent.next(this.documents.slice());
      }
    )
  }

//Add document function
  addDocument(document: Document) {
    if(!document){
      return;
    }

    document.id = '';
    const headers = new HttpHeaders({'Content-Type':'application/json'});
    this.http.post<{ message: string, document:Document}>('https://cmsproject-4163e.firebaseio.com/documents.json',
    document,
    { headers: headers })
    .subscribe(
      (responseData) => {
        this.documents.push(responseData.document);

      }
    );
  }
```

Comment: Most likely what you're getting from db is an object and .sort() must be applied to arrays. Test it doing a console.log(typeof this.documents)

Comment: I tested it out and the project is returning an object, but not an array as seen here: [Sort error](https://imgur.com/a/5VuQ346.)

Comment: That's exactly what I supposed, so you cant apply sort function to an object you need to convert it to an array in order to sort it.